# Messenger chatbot get started button not shown to non tester users

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

I have a facebook messenger chatbot app that works perfect with users that get tester-role.

In the app dashboard I see that that app is approved as public and is live.

My issue is that users (that not get any role in the app dashboard) can't see the `start button` and can't start conversion with the bot.

I read that I need approve on `page_message`, but I can't see this option on the submission items.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to also submit your bot for approval in the Messenger tab for your app. Just setting it to live won't make it available to all users.